# Which is faster, multiplication or subtraction?

Tags: c, performance, optimization

I'm currently doing a University project which is marked heavily upon the speed and efficiency of my solution. Minor changes I make to the code have massive impacts, as the particular function I am writing is called many hundreds of thousands of times.

I have written the main functionality of my project now, and am currently in the process of optimising everything I possibly can. One particular part of my code that I am questioning looks like this:

```
array[i] *= -1;
```

Which I was considering optimising to:

```
array[i] = 0 - array[i];
```

Would changing this code actually affect the speed? Is a subtraction operation faster than a multiplication operation? Or is this kind of issue a thing of the past?

Comment: Try it and see. It very much depends on your architecture.

Comment: Flip the sign bit :) That's the quickest (but I agree, this is all architecture dependent)

Comment: It is mostly unnecessary to do such pre-optimization, any half decent compiler will optimize the code for you anyway.

Comment: @ppeterka That only works on a one's complement system, which is ... unlikely to be what the OP has.

Comment: Btw, I have to wonder: why didn't you simply do `array[i] = -array[i]`? It's much easier to understand anyway.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Overlooking the fact that you should probably use this instead:

```
array[i] = -array[i];
```

as it's much clearer IMO since it directly states intent, lets check what the compiler does (GCC 4.7.2 on x86-64) for this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    t *= -1;
    return 0;
}
```

```
gcc -S mult.c -o 1.s
```

And for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    t = 0 - t;
    return 0;
}
```

```
gcc -S sub.c -o 2.s
```

Now compare the two assembly outputs:

```
diff 1.s 2.s
```

Nothing is printed. The compiler generated the same exact code for both versions. So the answer is: it doesn't matter what you use. The compiler will choose whatever is fastest. This is a pretty easy optimization to make (if you can even call it an optimization), so we can assume that virtually every compiler out there will pick the fastest way to do it for a given CPU architecture.

For reference, the generated code is:

```
int main()
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
       mov    edi,0x0
       call   12 
       mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax

    t *= -1;
       neg    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]

    t = 0 - t;
       neg    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]

    return 0;
       mov    eax,0x0
}
```

In both cases, it uses NEG to negate the value. `t *= -1` and `t = 0 - t` both generate:

```
neg QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
```

Answer (score 14):

There's only one sane way of going about optimization, and that is by measuring the performance of your application. A good profiler will be able to tell you a lot, but simply timing the execution of your program and various modifications can also be of great help. I'd go with the profiler first, though to find where the bottlenecks are.

As for your specific question, as others have pointed out this will be highly architecture dependant.

Answer (score 5):

Compilers are smart enough to convert this to an efficient operation. For example

C source

```
void f()
{
    int a = 7, b = 7;
    a *= -1;
    b = -b;
}
```

gives using `gcc -S a.c`

```
    .file    "a.c"
    .text
    .globl    f
    .type    f, @function
f:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $7, -8(%rbp) ; assign 7
    movl    $7, -4(%rbp) ; assign 7
    negl    -8(%rbp)     ; negate variable
    negl    -4(%rbp)     ; negate variable
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size    f, .-f
    .ident    "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

This is on a PC using Ubuntu 12.04 and gcc 4.6.3. Your architecture might be different.

Answer (score 4):

Multiplication will be slower on just about every device. It's a more complex operation.

However your compiler may well be smart enough to do the transformation itsself.
And on modern CPUs operations can get overlapped in such a way that the extra time for the instruction doesn't result in the execution time being increased as it's overlapped with other work.
And most likely it's so small a difference as to be unmeasurable without significant effort unless you are doing it many millions of times.

In general write clear code first, and optimize it if it is necessary later.
If you want the negative value of a variable write "-value" rather than "-1*value" as it more accurately reflects your intent, rather than just being a way to calculate it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what gcc 4.6.1 does with -O:

```
double a1(double b) { return -b; }       // xors sign bit with constant, 2 instr
                                         // movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm1   (instr 1)
                                         // xorpd   %xmm1, %xmm0        (instr 2)
                                         // ret                     (not counted)
double a2(double b) { return -1.0*b; }   // xors sign bit with constant, 2 instr
                                         // same code as above
double a3(double b) { return 0.0-b; }    // substract b from 0,  3 instructions
                                         // xorpd   %xmm1, %xmm1
                                         // subsd   %xmm0, %xmm1
                                         // movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0    (+ret)
int a4(int a){return -a;}                // neg rax   (+ret)  1 instruction
int a5(int a){return a*(-1);}            // neg rax
int a6(int a){return 0-a;}               // neg rax
double a7(double b) { return 0-b;}       // same as a3() -- 3 instructions
```

Thus, the suggested optimization makes it worse on this compiler (depending on array type).

Then about the question of multiplications being slower than additions. A rule of thumb is that *if multiplications are as fast as additions*, we are talking about DSP architectures or DSP extensions: Texas C64, Arm NEON, Arm VFP, MMX, SSE. The same goes for many floating point extensions, starting from Pentium, where both FADD and FMUL have a latency of 3 cycles and throughput of 1 instruction per cycle. ARM integer core also executes multiplications in 1 cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, trying to clean up my mess, and transform my sillyness into useful knowledge, not only for myself, but others as well.

### Main conclusion and summary:

**This kind of optimization is done automatically by the compiler, in this case both approaches got compiled to one single ASM instruction on x86.** (see above posts)  Don't make the compiler's work tougher than it has to be, just do what the logic implies.

Several answers show that this is compiled to the exact same instruction in both ways.

**TL;DR**

To remedy the blunder I made regarding this topic, I decided to dedicate some efforts to clear this up for myself - and for those who suffer from mental outages like I did when answering this question with a miraculously bad answer...

Negating a number depends on the architecture, and how data is represented.

### Sign and magnitude representation

Somehow I assumed that this implementation is used - it is not. This represents numbers as one sign bit, and all the rest for the value. So it can represent numbers from -2<sup>n-1</sup>-1 to 2<sup>n-1</sup>-1, and has a negative zero value too. In this kind of representation, it would be enough to flip the sign bit:

```
input ^ -0; // as the negative zero has all bits but the MSB as zero
```

### One's complement representation

A [one's complement integer representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) represents negative numbers as the bitwise negation of the positive representation. This is however not really used, from the 8080 on, two's compliment is used. A strange consequence of this representation is the negative zero, which can give a lot of troubles. Also, the numbers represented range from -2<sup>n-1</sup>-1 to 2<sup>n-1</sup>-1 where n is the number of bits the numbers are stored on.

In this case, the quickest "manual" way of negating a number would be to flip all the bits representing the sign:

```
input ^ 0xFFFFFFFF; //assuming 32 bits architecture
```

or

```
input ^ -0; //as negative zero is a "full one" binary value
```

### Two's complement representation

The more widely (always?) used  representation is the [two's complement system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). It represents numbers from -2<sup>n-1</sup> to 2<sup>n-1</sup>-1, and has only one zero value. It represents the positive range as their ordinary binary representation. However, adding 1 to 2<sup>n-1</sup>-1 (represented by having 1 in all the bits other than the MSB) will result in -2<sup>n-1</sup> (represented a 1 at MSB, and all other bits zero).

Negating a two's complement number manually would need negating all the bits and adding 1:

```
(input ^ -1) + 1 //as -1 is represented by all bits as 1
```

**However** as the range of negative values is broader than that of the positive values, the most negative number does not have a positive counterpart in this representation, this has to be taken into count, when dealing with these numbers! Inverting the most negative value would result in itself, just as it happens with zero (for sake of simplicity, in 8 bits)

```
most negative number: -128, represented as 10000000
inverting all bits: 01111111
adding one: 10000000 -> -128 again
```

But please, everyone* remember: premature optimization is the root of all evil! (and with the optimizers these are a thing of the past on any resourceful architectures)

*: the OP is already through this, so this is for all others, like me.

<sub>(Note to self: being (prematurely) silly is the root of all the (rightful) downvotes.)</sub>

Comment: Signed integers on most current architectures (including x86) don't have a "sign bit".

Comment: Try this on the machine you have and see if you get the right result. I suspect you won't. Start with trying it on a 0.

Comment: Yeah, but XORing `-1` at least on x86 will not give you the correct result: `0 ^ (-1) == -1`

Comment: Hmmm, true thoughts, thanks for them! I'll leave this here for a couple more minutes, and see if I can get the basic idea right - I might learn some more during this by doing the brainwork...

Comment: @Sergey: I thought about that, and altered my answer, but as others pointed it out, its still not correct.

Comment: Try testing what you post before you do: `0 ^ (1 << 31) == -2147483648` using 32-bit integers. Bit shift of `32` makes absolutely zero sense.

Comment: @Sergey: would love to. I don't have access to any kind of C environment here... And you're right, shifting by 32 digits is off limits.

Comment: @ppeterka I hate to pick on the only part of your answer that no one else has complained about yet, but your Donald Knuth quote seems irrelevant here. "Premature optimization" means optimizing too early in the development process. The OP states "I have written the main functionality of my project now, **and am currently in the process of optimising everything**". When do you suggest he do it?

Comment: After reading up a bit I see my mistake, thanks guys, at least I learnt something!

Comment: @Nocturno: the reason I included the phrase was having seen (not to mention done) too many premature optimizations, and would have liked to spare those, who forgot the principle... It was not directed towards the OP, but all the others, who might make their life (and possibly other fellow colleagues') a living hell...

Comment: Tried to transform it to useful knowledge. Do you think this - in its current form fits, or should I delete it ? (I have doubts, as in this current form doesn't really answer the exact question, yet it might convey useful information for people finding this page in the future.)

Comment: And there I go again... You didn't spot my errors regarding n vs n-1 in the exponent of the range expressions... This is clearly not my day...

Comment: You left out that fact that multiplication is invariably slower than subtraction. That the compiler optimizes a multiply by the specific constant -1 doesn't change that.